# How to make all math equations bold by default?

Tags: equations, bold

I am using the `bm` package which provides the `\bm` command to boldify equations. 
However, all my equations need to be bold, and I find using the `\bm` command tedious. Is there a way to make the equations (including inline equations) bold by default without wrapping them with the `\bm` command?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `\boldmath` macro does this. It is provided by the LaTeX core and switches to bold math for all following math material. There is an `\unboldmath` to switch it off again. These macros must be used outside the math code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\boldmath

$x=2$

\[ x=2 \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Although I would love to know whether it is possible to "redefine" or somehow insert code automatically just after each \begin{equation} and $. Thanks again!

Comment: There is `\everymath{..}` and `\everydisplay{..}` which accept code which is executed every math mode or display math mode. But they might be redefined by some other code.

Comment: The `everyhook` package provides a more robust way to interact with the math and display hooks...