# How to make the equation very extended bold?

Tags: bold

How could choose the level of boldness?

The difficult point is that it is not bold the text.

Any idea?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}


\begin{document}


\boldmath\boldmath\boldmath{\boldmath
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}%
$\bullet$ Initialization: $x^0 \in X$, $\lambda \in R$

$\bullet$ Iterations $n\ge 0$: Update $\tau^n$, $\widehat{x}^n$ and $x^n$ as follows
\begin{equation}
    x=y\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `$\pmb{\pmb{\bm{a^2+b^2=c^2}}}$` with `\usepackage{amsmath,bm}`, but **Please, don't do that!** (Because every time someone uses `\pmb`, Gutenberg kills a kitten.)

Comment: Hi, thank you. But found it do not work for \begin{equation}\pmb{\pmb{\bm{a^2+b^2=c^2}}}  \end{equation}

Comment: Can you add a little mor information, maybe in form of a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html)?
@tohecz :-)

Comment: Is it something like this? If not, please be a bit more specific.

`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\let\origtextbf\textbf
\renewcommand\textbf[1]{\mathversion{bold}\origtextbf{#1}\mathversion{normal}}
\begin{document}
{
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}%
\begin{itemize}
\item Initialization: $x^0 \in X$, $\lambda \in R$
\item \textbf{Iterations $n\ge 0$: Update $\tau^n$, $\widehat{x}^n$ and $x^n$ as follows}
\end{itemize}
\begin{equation}
    x=y\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
}}
\end{document}`
Code taken from matheplanet.com/default3.html?call=viewtopic.php?topic=188829

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## I. Poor man's solution that should never be used

As I said in the comments, you can use so-called "poor-man's bold", even twice. However, the result is so bad that **every time you use it, Gutenberg kills a kitten.**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

Pythagoras' formula:
$ \pmb{\pmb{\bm{a^2+b^2=c^2}}} $

\end{document}
```

## II. What to do instead

You can just use `\bm` or `\boldmath` (see [How to make all math equations bold by default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25686/how-to-make-all-math-equations-bold-by-default?rq=1) for more details on `\boldmath`).

Additionally, you can switch to a font that distinguishes bold from non-bold better than Computer Modern or Latin Modern does, for example [New Century Schoolbook](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newcent/), loaded through `\usepackage{fouriernc}` (remember to load `bm` after all other font packages):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Pythagoras' formula:
\\
$ \bm{a^2+b^2=c^2} $
\\
$ a^2+b^2=c^2 $

\end{document}
```