# How to make all math bold by default in LuaLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, luatex, bold, unicode-math

I would like to make all of my equations bold by default in a LuaLaTeX document that uses the lmodern math font. The answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25686/how-to-make-all-math-equations-bold-by-default) suggests using \boldmath, but I can't get it to work while using my current font setup. How can I get bold math characters by default here without wrapping all equations in \mathbf?

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf} 

\begin{document} 

\[ a = \alpha\times\beta\] 

\[\mathbf{a = \alpha\times\beta}\] 

\boldmath 
\[a = \alpha\times\beta\] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no bold Latin Modern Math font.

Comment: True, but \mathbf works as expected in my example.

Comment: That just emboldens letters using the bold text font.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do by default in equations. I suppose I should reword my question slightly.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. I can understand making “F” bold as a vector, but not mass, which is a scalar quantity.

Comment: Oh, don't worry about that. I just wrote Newton's second law as an example equation. I won't need to use bold for vectors in my actual application. I just need the whole equation to be bold by default.

Comment: I went ahead and changed the sample equation to avoid confusion.

Comment: @egreg not here, with unicode-math, it changes the rules:-)

Comment: What's the reason for you to want all your equations bold? You should not do this.

Comment: @MaxNoe, in general I agree. For this particular project, however, I have a presentation with a lot of references to particles, isotopes, etc. that are surrounded by regular text. The scaling on the text together with a thick font makes the default line weight of the math look terrible. It's not a computationally intensive talk, so I don't have to worry much about complicated mathematical expressions. Having math mode default to bold makes the frequent symbols in the text look good without a lot of effort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\boldmath` selects the bold math version which would have bold versions of most or some of the math fonts set up in the "usual" math groups. However latin modern math has no bold font so this doesn't do anything useful here.

Normally `\boldmath` just affects alphabetic characters and selects the bold roman text font.

Unfortunately unicode-math uses the command names for a rather different purpose and this is the main incompatibility between the current unicode-math definitions and classic LaTeX math definitions. Here `\mathbf` is not changing the font but rather it is changing the *characters* within the same font so a is replaced by U+1D41A MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL A and similarly for the Greek (which would not be affected by `\mathbf` in classic TeX)

This means that the bold effect is not achieved by resetting a font, or an assignment to a math `\fam` but by stepping through token by token replacing tokens by alternative characters representing the bold. This means that while nothing's ever impossible hiding the explicit argument form here is likely to be tricky and fragile.

Other font sets such as stix may have more extensive bold support, allowing `\boldmath` to work as intended, or using an explicit `\mathbf` is probably the safest thing,