# \textbf in math expression returns error

Tags: math-mode, bold

When I try to use the expression

```
$\textbf{a \cdot (a \times b)}$
```

It returns

```
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ Identiteten $ \textbf{a \cdot (a \times b)}
```

and lots of warnings like this:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $.\textdef@ ...th {#1}\let \f@size 
#2\selectfont #3}}        Identiteten $ \textbf{a \cdot (a \times b)}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25686/how-to-make-all-math-equations-bold-by-default is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Use `\mathbf{}` instead. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong markup: surround each variable by `\mathbf`:

```
$\mathbf{a} \cdot (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b})$
```

Better yet, define a macro for your vectors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\vect{a} \cdot (\vect{a} \times \vect{b})$

\end{document}
```

The result will be the same, but you have *semantic* markup, which is better and you'll know why when you'll need to modify how vectors are printed or to extend the definition for covering also Greek letters.

Answer (score 4):

`\textbf{}` is meant for text mode only, i.e. non-math characters and symbols. To use a bold font (if really needed) `\mathbf{}` is to be used, for bold symbols like the `\times` `\bm{}` from `bm` package can be applied or the `\boldmath` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}  % bold math 
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Normal weight

$a \cdot (a \times b)$

\item Bold

$\mathbf{a \cdot (a \times b)}$

\item Bold symbols

$\mathbf{a \cdot (a \bm{\times} b)}$

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If `a` and `b` are vectors, the dot product here is of course zero ;-)

Comment: Do you mind just adding one with bm at the outer level and no be inside, just for comparison. So the OP can see that bm actually gives bold italic

Comment: @daleif: No go ahead, although I wanted to restrict the `\bm` for the `\times` in this example, but... go ahead

Comment: Restricted to a tablet, so I cannot make the image